# attaching a vertex buffer object to a vertex array object

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

I am trying to attach a vbo to a vao. However I only get it to work the "old" way:

```
bind vao
bind vbo
glVertexAttribPointer(...)
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(...)
unbind vbo
unbind vao
```

Now I want it to implement the new bindless way, I tried it like this:

```
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(...);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(...);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(...);
```

However then I only get a black screen.

Attaching the index buffer object to the vao works though:

```
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(...);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like I was missing

> glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(...)

Thus, the correct replacement would be

```
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(...);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(...);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(...);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(...);
```

And don't forget to set the stride in glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(...), it should not be 0!